# Add To Cart Button have not press event

Tags: magento2, product, addtocart, wishlist, compare

[image]I am new to magento 2.1..

I have a problem to show the products.Product is shown in that page but the issue is the when i am pressing add to cart button it is not pressing also same problem in add to wishlist,compare.

Comment: any javascript errors in browser console ?

Comment: yes but that js error for homepage

Comment: Please run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` & also check in `var\log`

Comment: still problem is there

Comment: Is there any Browser console error?